# Android: Programmatically set ImageView style

Tags: android, imageview, styles

I have a ImageView and I need to programmatically apply the style to this image instead of doing it in xml

```
<style name="mainicon">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/icon_background</item>
    <item name="android:foregroundTint">@drawable/foreground_selector</item>
    ...
</style>


val buttonImageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.main_button) as ImageView
```

My question is that how I can programmatically apply the style to this image view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't change style of created and attached `View`. style may be set in constructor only, so if you are using XML declaration then style is already applied there (by `style` attribute, without `android:` prefix)

you may remove your current `View` and add new in the same place with new style applied by contructor

```
new ImageView(context, null, R.style.mainicon);
```

or using `ContextThemeWrapper`

```
new ImageView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.mainicon));
```

as an option you may also define in XML two `ImageView`s with different styles and switching their `Visibility`. this isn't best solution for performance, as you will keep additional, not used `View` in memory, but with `Visiblity.GONE` it won't be drawn, so won't take much memory and it may be easier to switch visibility rather than removing/adding new `View`s